# Menu buttons in lists

Tags: gui-design

I have this list of folders:

[image]

The dots open a action menu for every folder.

Users always have two complains:

1. They want the dot-menu besides the currently opened folder, because they want to do actions on it.
2. They don't want the dot-menu besides the currently opened folder, because they hit the dot-menu accidentally when pressing the back-arrow.

I always try to explain, that the back-arrow has the same function as the whole folder image and text, but they still want to press the tiny back-arrow.

In the image I removed the menu besides the arrow, but as I said, the complains about the missing menu started.

How can I get both, a back function that doesn't lead people to open the menu and a consistent menu button placement that looks like the others?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do something like this:

[image: overflow menu to the right]

It's pretty standard:

[image: Jira]
[image: Google Docs]

And that way your users won't accidentally click the wrong button. 
With your zebra stripes it should be pretty easy to see which button matches which folder.

Comment: This is on a tablet and I wanted to have the buttons near the thumbs of the user

Comment: @K.. This is not a valid argument, because your users say that they hit the dot-menu accidentally when pressing the back-arrow. Why on the tablet do  you want users to be able to access it with the thumb? This is not a phone

Comment: Because if I do it like you suggest, the menu buttons would be right in the middle of the screen. In landscape mode this is especially cumbersome.

Comment: Show a screenshot of the entire thing and you will probably get better answers.